# Specifying jceks file with Spark JDBC

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, jdbc, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to connect to Oracle via the `sqlContext.read.format("json")` method. Everything is going good but while creating the JDBC String, I have to specify the username and password for the database in the string :

```
val jdbcString = "jdbc:oracle:thin:USERNAME/PASSWORD@//HOSTNAME:PORT/SID"
```

However, I do have a `jceks` file present on HDFS which contains the password. I was wondering if there is any way that I can leverage that file to connect to JDBC instead of plain-text password? Like in Sqoop, we can do :

```
sqoop import -Dhadoop.security.credential.provider.path=jceks://hdfs/data/credentials/oracle.password.jceks
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This was achieved using `CredentialProviderFactory`.

```scala
import org.apache.hadoop.security.alias.CredentialProviderFactory

val conf = new org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration()
val alias = "password.alias"
val jceksPath = "jceks://hdfs/user/data/alias/MySQL.password.jceks"

conf.set(CredentialProviderFactory.CREDENTIAL_PROVIDER_PATH, jceksPath)

//getPassword Returns Array[Char]
val password = conf.getPassword(alias).mkString
```

Answer (score 0):

The Oracle JDBC thin driver doesn't support extracting the password from a jceks file. It supports wallets instead (password can be stored in a wallet).

Comment: I use jceks file while sqooping without any issues. This issue is more closely related to Hadoop and Spark than Oracle.